# (Chrome) Li hover not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

I have a page that I made here: http://foxrothschild.com/startuptoolkit/index.html

The nav on the left hand side has an a:hover effect for the background color:

```
.ca-menu li:hover{
background: rgba(153, 191, 204, 0.4) !important;
}
```

Don't know why, but in chrome it's not firing. Works in all other broswers (Firefox, IE, Safari).

Any ideas?

Comment: @Mr.Alien that's weird, it's not working for me at all. The background color isn't changing at all.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome as well, however I notice that the background effect is animated, and takes a very long time to do so.

Comment: @IgorShults, that was a mistake on my part. I don't know why, but it's not working for me. I've closed chrome, restarted, cleared the cache, I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but you have set: "transition: all 30000ms linear;", i think that are many miliseconds haha :)

You can set 300ms in all of transitions:

```
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all ms linear;
```

Hope that helps! :)